# Python issue with appending JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am having an issue, when I want to append the json file to change the state of the device connected to the server socket from connected to disconnected it will add extra }} in my json file which then will break the json file and give me the following error.

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 17 column 2 (char 406).

It works normally on the first connect an disconnect no issues but when the devices reconnects to change the state to Connected for some reason it adds the }} at the end.

python code:

```
def updatedevices(mac, devicename, state, contactone, filename='devices.json'):
 data = """[{mac: {"devicename": devicename,"state": state,"contactone": contactone}}]"""
 with open(filename,'r+') as file:
    file_data = json.load(file)
    if mac not in file_data:
        file_data.update(data)
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(file_data, file, indent = 4)
    else:
        pass
    if mac in file_data and state == 'disconnected':
        file_data[mac]['state'] = 'disconnected'
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(file_data, file, indent = 4)
    elif mac in file_data and state == 'connected':
        file_data[mac]['state'] = 'connected'
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(file_data, file, indent = 4)
    else:
        pass
```

this is what it does to the json file.

```
{
"00001": {
    "devicename": "Device Name 1",
    "state": "connected",
    "contactone": "5555558987"
},
"00002": {
    "devicename": "Device Name 2",
    "state": "connected",
    "contactone": "5555558987"
},
"00003": {
    "devicename": "Device Name 3",
    "state": "connected",
    "contactone": "5555558987"
}}
}
```

At the end it will add
}
}

Comment: You open the file with r+, which means that if you overwrite the data in the file after changing it and the new data is a few characters shorter than the old data, the last characters of the old data will remain in the file. They're not added, they're left over. A simple solution would be to open it for reading, read, modify the data in memory and then open it for writing and just overwrite the old file.

Comment: In your own words: if the file contains `apple` and then you do `file.seek(0)` and `file.write('pear')` and close the file, what do you think the file will end up containing afterwards? Why? Try that simpler example first, and you should see the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel awh! i see now opps!!! make sense I was getting tied up in thinking i was doing something wrong with the json.